# Connected Sheets cannot be targeted with macros or Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

As the update for Connected Sheets has rolled out, G Suite domains are (apparently) being upgraded from an initial BigQuery data connector that made use of the DataSourceTable object (ref below) to display extracted BigQuery data.

With the Connected Sheets upgrade, data extracted from a BigQuery source is no longer a DataSourceTable and, therefore, cannot be targeted in a recorded macro or a Script.

When trying to access BigQuery extracted data sets as a DataSourceTable, I receive an error:

Code:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:F').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDataSourceTables().forEach(function(dataSourceTable) { dataSourceTable.waitForCompletion(300) });
```

Error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshData' of undefined`

When attempting to programmatically define or manipulate BigQuery datasource, I receive an error:

Code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var spec = SpreadsheetApp.newDataSourceSpec()
           .asBigQuery()
           .setProjectId('onerockwell-qa-sites')
           .setRawQuery('select * from `dw.jira_issues` limit 10')
           .build();
var dataSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheetWithDataSourceTable(spec);
var dataSourceTable = dataSheet.getDataSourceTables()[0];
dataSourceTable.waitForCompletion(60);
Logger.log("Data execution state: %s.", dataSourceTable.getStatus().getExecutionState());
```

Error:
`Exception: Not permitted to act on data sources. Please contact your G Suite administrator to enable the feature.`

Has anyone else experienced this disruption?

ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - Connected Sheets have not been available for use with Sheets Macro Recording, Apps Script, or Sheets API.

This is changing: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/connected-sheets-api-apps-script.html

Roll-out starting August 26, 2020 and into September.

---

More detail as to my original question: My domain was on an old version of connections to BigQuery that used DataSourceTables -- and this did support macro targeting and Apps Script. We were auto-upgraded to Connected Sheets and lost these abilities. It seems we will now get the capabilities back with the new upgrades for Connected Sheets linked above.